# Set "Enforce inbound rules on PrivateLink traffic" setting in AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, amazon-elb, aws-security-group

In order to allow API Gateway access to my private Network Load Balancer in AWS, I need to set the property `Enforce inbound rules on PrivateLink traffic` to `Off` ([see reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-security-groups.html)). This is very easy to do from the AWS Console, simply go to the Security tab for the specified Load Balancer:
[image]

However, after looking in both the [Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticloadbalancing.LoadBalancer.html) and [Security Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.SecurityGroup.html) CDK references, I cannot find a way to do this from CDK. Even vanilla CloudFormation seems to have no property associated with this feature ([AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html), [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-securitygroup.html)). Is there any way to set this property from CDK? I have a strict mandate to automate all infrastructure.

Comment: How does toggling that option affect the attached security group(s)?

Comment: From what I can tell, it doesn't affect the security group at all. It looks like its a property of the Load Balancer, based on the fact that this property only appears in the AWS docs for Load Balancers, e.g., https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elbv2/set-security-groups.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-security-groups.html. Seems the logic, more or less, is to bypass the security group if this property is enabled for a Load Balancer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR**  Use a Custom Resource to set the property with a `SetSecurityGroups` SDK call.

The [SetSecurityGroups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/APIReference/API_SetSecurityGroups.html) API has a `EnforceSecurityGroupInboundRulesOnPrivateLinkTraffic` parameter, settable to `on` or `off`.  See [Set up a Network Load Balancer for API Gateway private integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-nlb-for-vpclink-using-console.html) in the docs.

You can integrate this API call with your CDK app using a [Custom Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#custom-resources).  Custom Resources are a fallback option in cases where a property isn't supported by CloudFormation.  The concept exists in both the CDK and CloudFormation.  Custom Resources are typically backed by a Lambda, which CloudFormation invokes for you during deployment.  The CDK offers several flavors of Custom Resource.  The options can be overwhelming.

Luckily, you can probably use [AwsCustomResource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources.AwsCustomResource.html), a construct tailored to making AWS SDK calls.  Pass `SetSecurityGroups` as the `action` prop and `EnforceSecurityGroupInboundRulesOnPrivateLinkTraffic: off` as a `parameter`.

Answer (score 2):

Enforce inbound rules on PrivateLink traffic is now availabe in CFN
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer.html#cfn-elasticloadbalancingv2-loadbalancer-enforcesecuritygroupinboundrulesonprivatelinktraffic